# How to disable touch gestures on SciSurface modifiers

Tags: scichart

I have WPF MVVM app. On one screen I'm using SciChartSurface and in some case I need to overlay it with dialog. Problem is, that SciChartSurface modifiers are responsive even thru another grid overlaying whole SciChartSurface. Is there any way to disable this touch gestures catching without disabling modifiers?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In [SciChart WPF](http://scichart.com/wpf-chart-features) v4 & 5 you can disable touch interaction by setting the flag to false.

```
public static bool MainGrid.RegisterTouchEvents { get; set; }
```

This will prevent all touch input processing for all SciChartSurfaces in the application.

Is this the desired outcome or did you want something else?